# Refreshing and alerting only when a keyword appears?

Tags: internet, browser, browser-addons

I know of the addons which reload the page and inform about any change on the website like Check4Change and Reload Every for Firefox. However, I'd love to have something which not only looks for any change but for a particular keyword or a list of keywords. I mean: something that I can configure to look for, say, "Jesse James" and it reloads every n seconds but gives me an alert/sound only when this keyword appears on the site, ignoring any other content chagne. Is there anything like this for any browser?

Answer (score 1):

Consider testing [sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) that performs pattern matching :

> A visual technology to search and automate graphical user interfaces
>   using screenshots

Maybe it's overkill, so another approach is to install [mozrepl Firefox add on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozrepl/), and then you will be able to control Firefox from command line in JavaScript. You can easily search a string in the whole page like in this screen-shot : [image: mozrepl screenshot]

Comment: Thank you but it's not exactly what I want. I mean - there's a possibility it would work but it's just too complex for such an easy purpose.

Comment: See my post edit, added MozRepl, I think that's suits your needs better.